# GLSL shadow multiplication doesn't work

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader

I'm in front of a very strange problem which seems to originate from a simple multiplication in the fragment shader

I'm trying to calculate shadows using a framebuffer that renders only the depths from "light's perspective" which is a common tecnique for beginners easier to implement

Fragment Shader:

```
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2D   parquet;
uniform samplerCube depthMaps[15];

in vec2 TexCoords;

out vec4 color;
in vec3 Normal;  
in vec3 FragPos;  

uniform vec3  lightPos[15]; 
uniform vec3  lightColor[15];
uniform float intensity[15];

uniform float far_plane;
uniform vec3 viewPos;


float ShadowCalculation(vec3 fragPos, vec3 lightPost, samplerCube depthMaps)
{
    vec3 fragToLight = fragPos - lightPost; 
    float closestDepth = texture(depthMaps, fragToLight).r;
    // original depth value
    closestDepth *= far_plane;
    float currentDepth = length(fragToLight);
    float bias = 0.05; 
    float shadow = currentDepth - bias > closestDepth ? 1.0 : 0.0;

    return shadow;
}


void main()
{
    vec3 norm = normalize(Normal);

    vec3 lightDir = normalize(lightPos[0] - FragPos);
    float diff = max(dot(norm, lightDir), 0.0);
    vec3 diffuse = diff * lightColor[0];

    float _distance = length(vec3(FragPos - lightPos[0]));
    float attenuation =  1.0 / pow(_distance +1, 2);
    if(attenuation > 1.0)  attenuation = 1.0;

    float intens = intensity[0];
    if(intensity[0] > 150) intens = 150.0f;

    vec3 resulta = (diffuse * attenuation) * intens;

    //texture color
    vec3 tCol = vec3(texture(parquet, TexCoords));
    //gamma correction
    tCol.rgb = pow(tCol.rgb, vec3(0.45));

    vec3 colors = resulta * tCol * (1.0f - ShadowCalculation(FragPos, lightPos[0],  depthMaps[0]));  

    color = vec4(colors, 1.0f);
}
```

The last multiplication inside main() behaves strangely, multiplying the result of the diffuse light by the texture color renders nicely (so we have no shadows, just diffuse lightning)

```
//works
vec3 colors = resulta * tCol;
```

Multiplying the diffuse light by the shadow results renders also nicely (now we have no textures)

```
//works
vec3 colors = resulta * (1.0f - ShadowCalculation(FragPos, lightPos[0],  depthMaps[0]));
```

Doing all togheter, renders just a black screen. I've tried all sort of things in the fragment shader, but none worked.

Lastly, here is the fragment shader used to render the cubemap:

```
#version 330 core
in vec4 FragPos;
uniform vec3 lightPos;
uniform float far_plane;

void main()
{
    float lightDistance = length(FragPos.xyz - lightPos);
    // map to [0;1] range by dividing by far_plane
    lightDistance = lightDistance / far_plane;
    gl_FragDepth = lightDistance;
}
```

Can you spot any logical error? I'm using uniforms array buffers since i'll later need multiple lights at once

Comment: What makes you think the problem is with the multiplication? It's entirely possible that the problem is in your cube map. You are doing a comparison between a linear distance and what you constantly refer to as a "depth". Well, if that depth came from `gl_FragDepth` (that is, you rendered with a depth buffer), then it almost certainly is not *linear*. So you're comparing two values that aren't computed in the same way.

Comment: Add that to your question, where it will be legible.

Comment: Shouldn't the fragment shader of the cubemap have an output variable? It doesn't output any color for as far as I can see.

Comment: The cubemap itself is rendered trought the depth component of the framebuffer to which it's attached to, there's no need to use a color buffer in this case since we're not interested in rendering the surrouning colors "seen by the light"

Answer (score 0):

After a while trying to visually debug the shader's output I finally found the error, I was binding the depthmap's cubemap texture incorrectly and this caused the strange behaviour I was seeing in the last multiplication

Lesson learned: It' not always fragment's fault